# ssh argument command not passed

Tags: centos, ssh, command

Doing this command:

```
iptables -I INPUT -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 70 \ --algo bm --string 'GET /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.' -j DROP
```

I got this error on ssh console: "bad argument (--algo)".
How can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
iptables -I INPUT -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 70 \
--algo bm --string 'GET /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.' -j DROP
```

or:

`iptables -I INPUT -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 70 --algo bm --string 'GET /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.' -j DROP`

The backslash (`\`) is used when you want to write a shell command on multiple lines.